# How to create a two column layout

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if there is a way to setup a two-column layout with the following:

I have

```
<div>
   <div>title </div>
   <div>content </div>
   <div>name </div>
   <div>data </div>
</div>

<div>
   <div>title </div>
   <div>content </div>
   <div>name </div>
   <div>data </div>
</div>

<div>
   <div>title </div>
   <div>content </div>
   <div>name </div>
   <div>data </div>
</div>

<div>
   <div>title </div>
   <div>content </div>
   <div>name </div>
   <div>data </div>
</div>

<div>
   <div>title </div>
   <div>content </div>
   <div>name </div>
   <div>data </div>
</div>


<div>
   <div>title </div>
   <div>content </div>
   <div>name </div>
   <div>data </div>
</div>


<div>
   <div>title </div>
   <div>content </div>
   <div>name </div>
   <div>data </div>
</div>



<div>
   <div>title </div>
   <div>content </div>
   <div>name </div>
   <div>data </div>
</div>



more....
```

I want the following:

```
title       title
content     content
name        name
data        data

title       title
content     content
name        name
data        data

title       title
content     content
name        name
data        data

title       title
content     content
name        name
data        data

title       title
content     content
name        name
data        data

more ....
```

I am not sure how to do this in CSS. Any ideas? Thanks so much!

Comment: Use html tables. They work well. Otherwise, with div, use `display: inline` and pre-fix the width of the divs.

Comment: HTML tables should only be used to display tabular data. For layout and positioning, consider CSS instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/fZse3/

```
<style>
#col1, #col2 {
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
}
</style>


  <div id="col1">
     <div>
        <div>title </div>
        <div>content </div>
        <div>name </div>
        <div>data </div>
     </div>

     <div>
        <div>title </div>
        <div>content </div>
        <div>name </div>
        <div>data </div>
     </div>
  </div>

  <div id="col2">
     <div>
        <div>title </div>
        <div>content </div>
        <div>name </div>
        <div>data </div>
     </div>

     <div>
        <div>title </div>
        <div>content </div>
        <div>name </div>
        <div>data </div>
     </div>
  </div>​
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy solution...

```
    <div id="1" style="float: left; width: 200px;">
    <div>
       <div>title </div>
       <div>content </div>
       <div>name </div>
       <div>data </div>
    </div>

    <div>
       <div>title </div>
       <div>content </div>
       <div>name </div>
       <div>data </div>
    </div>

    <div>
       <div>title </div>
       <div>content </div>
       <div>name </div>
       <div>data </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="2" style="float: left;  width: 200px;">
    <div>
       <div>title </div>
       <div>content </div>
       <div>name </div>
       <div>data </div>
    </div>


    <div>
       <div>title </div>
       <div>content </div>
       <div>name </div>
       <div>data </div>
    </div>


    <div>
       <div>title </div>
       <div>content </div>
       <div>name </div>
       <div>data </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see how it looks here...  [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C6KJa/)